# Deprecated ARMA module

Tags: arima

I'm following a Time Series Analysis module on DataCamp and tried using the exact same code in Jupyter notebook:

```
# Import the ARMA module from statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA

# Forecast the first AR(1) model
mod = ARMA(simulated_data_1, order=(1,0))
res = mod.fit()
res.plot_predict(start=990, end=1010)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: 
statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have
been removed in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the .
between arima and model) and statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX.

statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA makes use of the statespace framework and
is both well tested and maintained. It also offers alternative specialized
parameter estimators.
```

After making some adjustments by using the correct package, I was able to get a chart but not the confidence interval as in the first image.

```
# Import the ARMA module from statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
    
# Fit an AR(1) model to the first simulated data
model = ARIMA(simulated_data_1, order=(1,0,0))
result = model.fit()
    
plt.plot(simulated_data_1[990:])
plt.plot(result.predict(start=990, end=1010, ax=ax), color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I add in the confidence interval?